# How do I solve this maclaurin series problem?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Be

$$f(x)=\frac{(6-5x)}{(1-x)(2-x)}$$

how to find the MacLaurin series for $f(x)$?

I can split

$$f(x) \to f(x)= \frac{1}{(1-x)} + \frac{4}{(2-x)}$$

hence

$$f(x)= \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} x^n + \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{2^{n-1}}$$

is it right answer??

And how do I find  $f'''''(0)$?

Comment: Seems right.  You have the right idea, anyway.  As for that fifth derivative (really???) just take the fifth derivative of each of your sums and then add them together.  This works because the derivative is a linear operator.

Comment: You should finish by combining the two series into one as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n(1+2^{1-n}).$ The co-efficient of $x^5$ in this series is equal to $f^{(v)}(0)/5!.$